# Plotting latitude and longitude coordinates (from Bing Maps) in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wgs84, bing-maps

I have an excel spreadsheet containing latitude and longitude values for a set of businesses.  I want to plot the businesses in ArcMap.  I was told the latitude and longitude values were obtained from Bing Maps, which I believe uses the coordinate reference system WGS84 (I found this info on various forums, so it may be wrong!).

However when I plot the data using WGS84 (using the 'display xy data' function), the points do not appear to plot correctly. The points look to be systematically displaced west and slightly north.

Indeed, when I manually geocoded the food businesses (using the postcodes of the food businesses) this systematic displacement was evident (see image).  Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

[image]

Comment: What's the coordinate system of the other data? British National Grid? You'll need to set a geographic transformation. DF properties, coordinate systems tab, Transformations button.